# How can I set my mat-toolbar-row so that it's color is "primary"?

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, material-design

I'm fairly new to angular and I am having some trouble trying to change my mat-toolbar-row so its color="primary". I wasn't really sure how to make it work, It worked when I did the same thing for mat-toolbar but won't work for the row.

```
mat-toolbar-row color = "primary">Menu</mat-toolbar-row>
```

here is my code.

I was also having trouble changing the colors to a custom set of colors from the default pink-indigo theme that was installed with angular.

Comment: Did you let ng generated your app?  Did you choose scss or css? Do you have an style.scss fiile in you project?

Comment: I did let ng generate my app, i chose scss, i do have a style.scss

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

In case you have scss, you can set the style in the end of the 'global' styles.scss

```
.mat-toolbar-row {background-color: yellow;}
```

A better way is to define a 'global' class (in the styles.scss):

```
.bg-color-whatever {background-color: yellow}
```

This class can be set on the mat-toolbar-row:

```
<mat-toolbar-row class="bg-color-whatever">
```

This is just a tweak (hack), but it works fine.

If you want to change the global theme, you have two posibillities:

First: you can choose an other [predefined material theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme).

Second: you can create your own theme.

More Informations can you find here: [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)